# issue with displaying data from the server in a table

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios, datatable, vuejs3

When I display data from the server in a table, and conditionally, 25 rows should be displayed on the last page of pagination, and 10 rows are left to display, then I get an error that id is undefined.

Is it possible to somehow put restrictions on the display of data that is available and received from the server with my own code.

I use the [vue3-table-lite](https://github.com/linmasahiro/vue3-table-lite) library, I take the data from json-placeholder.

```html
<template>
  <table-lite
    :is-loading="table.isLoading"
    :is-re-search="table.isReSearch"
    :columns="table.columns"
    :rows="table.rows"
    :total="table.totalRecordCount"
    :sortable="table.sortable"
    :messages="table.messages"
    :page-options="table.pageOptions"
    @do-search="doSearch"
    @is-finished="tableLoadingFinish"
  ></table-lite>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, reactive } from "vue";
import TableLite from "vue3-table-lite/ts";
import axios from "axios";
import { data } from "./data";

const dataAsc = (offset: number, limit: any, response: any) => {
  // offset = offset;
  let data = [];
  for (let i = offset; i < limit; i++) {
    data.push({
      id: response.data[i].id,
      name: response.data[i].name,
      username: response.data[i].username,
      address: response.data[i].address,
      phone: response.data[i].phone,
      website: response.data[i].website,
      email: response.data[i].email,
      company: response.data[i].company,
    });
  }
  console.log(data);
  return data;
};

const dataDesc = (offset: number, limit: any, response: any) => {
  console.log(offset, limit, response);
  let data = [];
  for (let i = limit - 1; i >= offset; i--) {
    data.push({
      id: response.data[i].id,
      name: response.data[i].name,
      username: response.data[i].username,
      address: response.data[i].address,
      phone: response.data[i].phone,
      website: response.data[i].website,
      email: response.data[i].email,
      company: response.data[i].company,
    });
  }
  console.log(data);
  return data;
};

export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  components: { TableLite },
  setup() {
    const table = reactive({
      isLoading: false,
      isReSearch: false,
      columns: data,
      rows: [],
      totalRecordCount: 0,
      sortable: {
        order: "id",
        sort: "asc",
      },
      messages: {
        pagingInfo: "",
        // pageSizeChangeLabel: "Число строк:",
        // gotoPageLabel: "Перейти на страницу:",
        noDataAvailable: "Нет данных",
      },
      pageOptions: [
        {
          value: 15,
          text: "15/стр",
        },
        {
          value: 30,
          text: "30/стр",
        },
      ],
    });

    /**
     * Table search event
     */
    const doSearch = (
      offset: number,
      limit: number,
      order: string,
      sort: string
    ) => {
      table.isLoading = true;
      table.isReSearch = offset == undefined ? true : false;

      let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
      axios.get(url).then((response: any) => {
        if ((offset >= 15 || limit >= 30) && limit <= response.data.length - 30) {
          limit = offset + 30;
        }
        if (sort === "asc") {
          table.rows = dataAsc(offset, limit, response);
        } else {
          table.rows = dataDesc(offset, limit, response);
        }

        // refresh table rows
        table.totalRecordCount = response.data.length;
        table.sortable.order = order;
        table.sortable.sort = sort;
        // console.log(offset, limit, order, sort);
      });
    };

    /**
     * Table search finished event
     */
    const tableLoadingFinish = (elements: any) => {
      table.isLoading = false;
    };

    // Get data first
    doSearch(0, table.pageOptions[0].value, "id", "asc");

    return {
      table,
      doSearch,
      tableLoadingFinish,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

data.ts file:

```js
export const data = [
  {
    label: "ID",
    field: "id",
    sortable: true,
    isKey: true,
    width: "3%",
  },
  {
    label: "Имя",
    field: "name",
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    label: "Ник",
    field: "username",
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    label: "Адрес",
    field: "address",
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    label: "Телефон",
    field: "phone",
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    label: "Сайт",
    field: "website",
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    label: "Почта",
    field: "email",
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    label: "Компания",
    field: "company",
    sortable: true,
  },
];
```

[image: Error]

Comment: In there `response.data[i].id`, there is something `null/undefined`. Can be `data`, `i`, `id`. Please try to use your Vue devtools to see which one is faulty.

Comment: "undefined" is set when there is no more data[i].id to display, the question is rather how to properly implement the check: when the table should display 25 rows of data, but only 10 come from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it was necessary to create a condition to check that limit exceeds the number of rows of data:

```
      const doSearch = (
        offset: number,
        limit: number,
        order: string,
        sort: string
      ) => {
        table.isLoading = true
        table.isReSearch = offset == undefined ? true : false
        const i = limit

        const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
        axios.get(url).then((response: any) => {
          limit = offset + i
          if (limit >= response.data.length) {
            limit = response.data.length
          }
          if (sort === 'asc') {
            table.rows = dataAsc(offset, limit, response)
          } else {
            table.rows = dataDesc(offset, limit, response)
          }

          // refresh table rows
          table.totalRecordCount = response.data.length
          table.sortable.order = order
          table.sortable.sort = sort
        })
      }
```